# Does Ubuntu have a command line configuration tool

Tags: command-line, configuration

I'm looking for a **command line** tool to configure Ubuntu 20+. (Firewall, Users, Networking, Services, Hardware.) Just like Suse has Yast, and CentOS has the Setup tool.

I know Ubuntu used to have Ubuntu-tweak, but that has been discontinued, and its successors don't seem to have command line support. And I really don't want to run a gui (gnome/unity/etc).

Is there such a tool available?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware that there is a single command-line tool for configuring everything. However, Ubuntu have a number of different options available:

1. Some command-line tools exist to provide an easier interface for specific purposes, e.g.:

   - [`ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ufw.8.html) - program for managing a netfilter/iptables firewall
   - [`adduser`, `addgroup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/adduser.8.html) - add a user or group to the system
2. Another method is using "generic" configuration files accompanied by a command-line tool. [Netplan](https://netplan.io) is a good example of this. Netplan uses `.yaml` [configuration files](https://netplan.io/examples/) located in `/etc/netplan/`, and the command `netplan <option>` is used to apply the configuration, get system info etc.
3. Some packages allow you to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <package name>`. This will rerun the Debian installer ([debconf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/debconf.7.html)) in the chosen mode (dialog, readline, Gnome etc.), if this is included in the post installation script for the package. Many packages support this option - [postfix](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix) is a good example.

   - In addition, running `dpkg --configure -a` will configure all unconfigured packages (see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516458/what-does-dpkg-configure-a-do)).
4. Finally, for an all-round configuration tool with a ton of modules there is [Webmin](https://www.webmin.com/), which provides an intuitive web-interface to configure various elements of Unix and Linux systems. This is especially useful for servers. The [default module list](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Modules) is quite extensive, and there are additional [3rd party modules](https://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?modules=1) available.

   - [Installation instructions](https://www.webmin.com/deb.html) for Ubuntu are on the Webmin website as well.